# Improved SGBM based on previous frames result

Tags: computer-vision, disparity-mapping

I was wondering if there is any good method to make SGBM process faster, by taking the info from the previous video frame.

I think that it can be made faster by searching correspondences only near the distance of the disparity of previous frame. The problem I see in this is when from one frame to the next, the block passes  from an object to background of viceversa. I think, in case to be possible, is an interesting improve to be made, and I have looked for it but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You have told what is the problem, if the scene is in motion. 
I managed to wrote some algorithm that take in consideration the critical zone around the objects' borders, they were a little more accurate but very slower than SGBM.

Maybe you can simply set the maximum and the minimum value of disparity in a reasonable range of what you find in the previous frame instead of "safe values". In my experience wuth OpenCV, stereoBM is faster but not so good as SGBM, and SGBM is better optimized than any other algorithm written by oneself (always in my experience).

Maybe you can have some better (faster) result using the CUDA algorithm (SGBM processed in GPU). My group and I are working on that.